# How to get the link with long tap with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, gesture

Basically I want to get the link the user tap on (long tap gesture) on IE 10.

For click event, I found this

```
function linkClick(e) {
  alert(e.target.href);
}
links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
  links[i].addEventListener('click', linkClick, false);
```

So obviously I have to attach the MSGesture object on each link. Here's [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh968249.aspx) from Microsoft documentation but I can't figure it out how to do it for links on a page.

Answer (score 0):

I have a tapHold method in http://deeptissuejs.com a JavaScript Touch Gesture Library that should give you cross-platform touch, mspointer and mouse support.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
function linkClick(e) {
  alert(e.target.href);
}
links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
  links[i].addEventListener('MSGestureTap', linkClick, false);
```